# 130 and 1033 errors on my database

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry, I'm french and i hope you'll understand what I'll try to explain ...
I work with the CMS Joomla and Wampserver. After an update of the PHP version, Wamp didn't work. Then, before the reinstall of this, I saved the www directory ... and forgot the databases ... I deleted the directory. Happily (perhaps ?) I remembered the databases before reinstalling. And I tried to retrieve these with a software to recover deleted files. I recovered a lot of files with .frm, .MYD and MYI extensions.
I created a new database and copy these files in the mysql directory to verify the integrity.
But, if a few of these are ok, others have problems. 
For one : phpMyAdmin shows there are 10 datas but, if I want to open the table error 1194, table is marked as crashed and should be repair. I tried it by the command Repair in phpMyAdmin but after it, there is no more recording !

In an other : Error 130 Incorrect file format name_table

In others : #1033 - Incorrect information in file : "name_table.frm"

Is it possible to repair that ? Not with the repair command. I tried it with cmd but the result is only a ->

It's very important for me because these are the Virtumart products tables ...

Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Comment: Do you have anything backed up as SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Unfortunatly, it seems that the last backup was made 3 months before the crash ...There has been a lot of changes between the last backup and the crash. I'm looking into all may computer to be sure ... My memory is bad : I don't remember if I made an update of Joomla and Virtuemart after this last backup ... And I don't remember wich version of Mysql was installed when the recovered files worked.I struck violently from the blunder I made, but it does not help me ... I'ld not have to start all again ...